# Does Pandas have createOrReplaceTempView()

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am actually new to Pandas. I do know that spark have `createOrReplaceTempView()`, which makes it easy to use dataframe to directly run sql queries.

However, I wanted to achieve the same using Pandas sql. I can do this using pandas dataframe.

I am not sure if my requirement can be achieved in different way as well.

Below is the query -

```
INSERT INTO out_table
SELECT ss.*, 'identity', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0
FROM table1 ss
LEFT JOIN table2 ss2 ON ss.run_id = ss2.run_id AND ss.busdate = ss2.busdate AND ss.code = ss2.code
WHERE ss2.run_id IS NULL
AND ss.run_id = (
    SELECT MAX(ss2.run_id)
    FROM table2 ss2
    WHERE ss2.busdate = ss.busdate AND ss2.code = ss.code
)
AND ss.busdate = 'date'
```

I have respective `dataframes` for `table1`, `table2`. All I want to do is use respective dataframes instead of the tables.

I am using oracle connection, `cursor.executemany(query)`.

So is it possible to do in pandas or is there any different workaround.